# app freezes by using avplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have used AVPlayer for streaming audio. But it makes the app freeze after some seconds.

```
 AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[songsarray objectAtIndex:songnumber]]];
self.songPlayer = player;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[songPlayer currentItem]];
[self.songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[self.songPlayer play];
```

I am npt getting proper way for streaming audio. If anyone has some idea please help me out.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Edit your code with KVO method implementation.

Comment: KVO method implementation?

Comment: yes, [self.songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil]; this line denote you create KVO for status property. So you must implement KVO context method.

Comment: I have already used this method @iAmbitious